# MySQL 5.7 group by latest record

Tags: mysql

Very simple select, but I'm confused:

```
create table users (id int, type int);
insert into users values(1, 100), (2, 101), (3, 100);
mysql> select * from users;                                                                                                               
+------+------+                                                                                                                           
| id   | type |                                                                                                                                                                                                   
+------+------+                                                                                                                                                                                                   
|    1 |  100 |                                                                                                                                                                                                   
|    2 |  101 |                                                                                                                                                                                                   
|    3 |  100 |                                                                                                                                                                                                   
+------+------+
```

I want to get the result:

```
+------+------+
| id   | type |
+------+------+
|    3 |  100 |
|    2 |  101 |
+------+------+
```

My query is:

MySQL version 5.7 returns:

```
mysql> select * from (select * from users order by id desc) as t group by type;
+------+------+
| id   | type |
+------+------+
|    1 |  100 |
|    2 |  101 |
+------+------+
```

At MySQL 5.5 it works as expected. sql_mode is NULL

Thanks for the replies. Extended table to have more clear results:

```
create table users (id int, type int, level int);
insert into users values(1, 100, 1000), (2, 101, 1001), (3, 100, 1002);

mysql> select max(id), type, level from users group by type;
+---------+------+-------+
| max(id) | type | level |
+---------+------+-------+
|       3 |  100 |  1000 | <- expected 1002
|       2 |  101 |  1001 |
+---------+------+-------+
```

This works:

```
mysql> SELECT t1.* FROM users t1 INNER JOIN (SELECT type, MAX(id) AS max_id FROM users GROUP BY type) t2 ON t1.type = t2.type AND t1.id = t2.max_id ORDER BY id DESC;
+------+------+-------+
| id   | type | level |
+------+------+-------+
|    3 |  100 |  1002 |
|    2 |  101 |  1001 |
+------+------+-------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For completeness I can offer the following query which would work if you wanted to return entire records with an arbitrary number of columns.

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM users t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT type, MAX(id) AS max_id
    FROM users
    GROUP BY type
) t2
    ON t1.type = t2.type AND
       t1.id   = t2.max_id
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use an aggregation function and group by

```
select max(id), type
from users 
group by type;
order by id desc
```

the result in mysql5.5  not based on group by is casual .. (this beahvior is deprecated  in sql and not allowed  in default sql_mode in 5.7)

Answer (score 0):

GROUP BY without aggregation is supported in very few SQL dialects (perhaps even only MySQL); the fact that it worked as you expected in 5.5 was (for the most part) just convenient, not guaranteed by MySQL. Officially, it grabs an effectively random value (encountered from the rows of the group) from the non-grouped, non-aggregated fields.