# MySQL 5.7 How to do GROUP BY with sorting?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

Similar to this issue: [MySQL 5.7 group by latest record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45149074/mysql-5-7-group-by-latest-record)

I'm not sure how to do this properly in 5.7. Also with possibility of 2nd sort column. Working query in 5.6 that I'm trying to replicate in 5.7:

```
SELECT id FROM test
GROUP BY category
ORDER BY sort1 DESC, sort2 DESC
```

id is not always the highest, so MAX(id) does not work.

Looking into the link above, the solution for single sort should be:

```
SELECT t1.* 
FROM test t1
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT category, max(sort) AS sort FROM test GROUP BY category
    ) t2 ON t2.category = t1.category AND t2.sort = t1.sort
```

But how will it work with 2 sorting?

Comment: Don't get why are you using group by without an aggregation function. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: If you don't use aggregate, why use `GROUP BY`?  You only use `GROUP BY` if you need to aggregate a column.  This will not even run on any other dbms.

Comment: @lamar & eric, you guys are correct. I have updated the query. I can't think of a good solution for 2 sorting other than creating a calculated sort maybe like SELECT (sort * 1000 + sort2) as sort_score

Comment: Make up your mind. Your question has drastically changed after your edit.

Answer (score 2):

You are using GROUP BY the wrong way.
Think of group by as a way to separate data row into different groups. Each group has multiple rows, based on the value of group by column.

Once you get those groups, selecting table columns (as in: `select *`) is like picking any row from that group randomly. This is not helpful nor useful.

Usually once we group records (or rows), we need to find meta information about those records. For example: get us the count of records in that group (as in: `select count(*)`), or the sum of values of a specific column in that group (as in: `select sum(price)`), or get the min, max or avg values.

So in a nutshell, when you use group by you should use on of the aggregation functions with it, otherwise it's not going to do you any good.

Comment: You are correct. I have updated the issue. I have it working for single sort, but unable to get it to work with 2 sorts.

Comment: Can you be more clear about what you mean by 2 sorts? Can you add more details in your question above?

Comment: Basically order by 2 fields: sort, sort2.

Comment: So what's wrong with this score you've just came up with?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you have the ORDER BY at your outer query, instead?

```
SELECT * 
  FROM (
        SELECT 100 AS id, 1 AS category, NULL AS sort
        UNION
        SELECT 200 AS id, 1 AS category, 2 AS sort
       ) dt
GROUP BY category
ORDER BY sort DESC;
```

It seems that what happened to the data when it was grouped, it took the first data while neglecting the ORDER BY DESC. On your first query, it ordered descending first then group by took the first record which is 200. And yes, this shouldn't be the way you should use GROUP BY. It is used in conjunction with aggregate functions.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work? In MySQL 5.6 putting the sort in the subquery works but not in MySQL 5.7

Comment: When I ran this in MySQL 5.7, the result is 100.

Answer (score 0):

when you select a column in a group by query that is not one of the columns you are grouping by, (ie, your `id`) you have no control over the value unless you use another aggregate function. If you want to sort, use MIN or MAX:

```
SELECT MAX(id), category, FROM `test2`
GROUP BY category; -- always returns 200

SELECT MIN(id), category, FROM `test2`
GROUP BY category; -- always returns 100
```

Comment: I'm unable to use MIN/MAX because the result id with the highest sorting might be in the middle.